# Loading a text file into a struct using C

Tags: c, printing, struct, io, load

I try to load the contents of a text file into a structure.

My idea looks like this:

I have two files, `struct.h` , `main.c` and a `list.txt` file .

in file `struct.h` :

```
struct analg {
    char word[6];
    char signature[6];
};
struct analg h[106];
FILE *fp;
```

In file `main.c` :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "struct.h"

void load() {
    fp = fopen("list.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("fail");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("file loaded!\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return;
}

void print() {

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        while(fgets(h[i].word, 6, fp)) {
            printf("%s", h[i].word);
        }
    }
    return;
 }

int main () {

int choice;

do {
    printf("choose L or P: ");
    scanf("%s", &choice);
    switch(choice) {
        case 'l': 
            load();
            printf("\n[l]oad - [p]rint\n");
            break;
        case 'p': 
            print();
            printf("\n[l]oad - [p]rint\n");
            break;
        default:        
            break;
       }
    }  while(choice!='q');

    return;
}
```

In file `list.txt` :

```
throw

timer

tones

tower

trace

trade

tread
```

So I try to load the text file by pressing the "L" to the structure, and then when I press the 'p' will be displayed, but it is not!

Comment: `scanf("%s", &choice);` expects a pointer to a `char` array. Also, case matters, you only test the lower case letters.

Comment: yes, and when I write p nothing works! only L!

Comment: @HaidoManeen Yes, that's because your code is broken, as DanielFischer said.

Comment: broken? I do not get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, I see there are 2 potential issues. The choice has to be a character to be switched based on `l` or `p`. You may have to add cases to handle the upper case also.

Another issue is that in `load` function, you are closing the file pointer. Hence, when you enter the `print` function `fgets` may not work as the `fp` is already closed.

To load your file into structure, the load has to be modified as

```
void load() {
fp = fopen("list.txt", "r");
if(fp == NULL) {
    printf("fail");
    return; // There was an error in original code as this was returning 1
}

do{
    fgets(h[count++].word, 6, fp); // Count is a global variable - no. of elements read
}while(!feof(fp));
printf("file loaded!\n");
fclose(fp);

return;
}
```

The corresponding print function would become

```
void print(){

  int i;
  printf("Inside print\n");

  for(i=0; i < count; i++) {
      printf("%s", h[i].word);
  }
 return;
 }
```

the main function would be,

int main (){

```
char choice;


do{
    printf("choose L or P: ");
    scanf("%c", &choice); //Only character is read and hence, %s is not required
    switch(choice){
    case 'l': 
        load();
        printf("\n[l]oad - [p]rint\n");
        break;
    case 'p': 
        print();
        printf("\n[l]oad - [p]rint\n");
        break;
    default:
    case 'q':
        break;
    }
} while(choice !='q');

return 0;
}
```

One last point. In the `scanf` statement if `scanf("%s", &choice);` is employed, then a runtime check error is generated when `main` exits, with a message that stack is corrupted around the variable `choice`.

Comment: ok you may not understand the question! I want to load the file into an array that is why I turn off the file in Load function!, I want to load the file into an array by structure and then work with the file without changing to something!

Comment: Sorry I didn't your current point also. You want to close the file in load, which should be ok. In print, you are reading from the file pointer. The file pointer is not a valid handle when invoke print.

Comment: so I think, I upload the file, close it, to have the file in the array in structure, print the file! , So I was thinking to do!

Comment: now I get it, eh problem that I do not read anything from the file, I tried your code and it works great. Thanks so much for your help, I appreciate it - @Ganesh

Answer (score 1):

I'll comment up what your code is doing:

```
void load() {
fp = fopen("list.txt", "r"); // opens the file for reading
if(fp == NULL) {
    printf("fail");          // if the file couldn't be opened, return an error
    return 1;                // (aside: a void function can't return an int)
}
else {

   printf("file loaded!\n"); // tell the user that the file was opened
}

fclose(fp);                  // close the file, having read nothing from it

return;
}
```

At no point do you read anything from the file. What you have in memory will therefore have no relation to whatever you have on disk.

C has no built-in means for serialising and deserialising structs so what you need to do is define a formal grammar for your file on disk and write code that can parse that grammar into your structs.

Comment: so I read the txt file but have not saved in structure. do you mean that?

Comment: so do you know how I should define a formal grammar for my file on disk and write code that can parse that grammar into my structs?

Comment: I think that what you're doing in print with `fgets` is probably the right sort of thing — you're just doing it in the wrong place (at least assuming you want all loading to be completed within `load`) and after you've closed the file so that you can no longer read from it. So probably do the `while(fgets(h[i].word, 6, fp))` in `load`, before you shut the file, and only the print[f]ing in `print`

Comment: thank you very much I did it like you said and it works! but a littleeeee problem! I just get the first row from my text file? , i tried `while(fgets(h[i].word, 6, fp))` in Load and  `printf("%s", h[i].word);` in Print?